# How to check if an email address exists or not without sending an email?

Tags: email, email-validation

I have a bunch of mails ids and I want to check all that mail is valid or not.

How it's possible to check without sending any mail.

Answer (score 2):

**Syntax Validation:** The most obvious part, people - however - know least about. There's more to email syntax validation than the simple PHP RegEx rule you're using. There's the IETF Standards (all the RFCs), but you'll also have to look at ISP-specific syntax checking, quoted words, domain literals, non-ASCII domains, etc.

**Disposable & Free Emails:** Next, before you use any server side code to check the given email address, it's recommended to check whether or not you're dealing with disposable emails (e.g. mailinator.com) or free emails (Gmail, Yahoo!, etc.) and act accordingly.

**Obvious Typos:** Now is the time to check for obvious misspellings and typos. (e.g. user@gnail.com would be corrected to user@gmail.com)
DNS validation, including MC record(s) lookup: Verify the DNS MX-Records for the given domain.

**SMTP connection, catch-all check:** Now for the meaty part, but also the most risky. Validating email addresses by establishing and then aborting an SMTP connection to the given mail server is still the only way to really find out if a mailbox actually exists. However, if executed in the false way, you will - really quickly - be blacklisted and considered a spammer.

From:

https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-check-if-an-e-mail-address-is-valid-without-e-mailing-it

**mailboxlayer API** - my clear favourite. It's basically free, safe, and comes with each and every validation tool necessary in order to properly validate email addresses.

**Kickbox.io** - great product, but this will cost you a little more. Advantage: They also offer list-cleaning.

**email-validator.net** - great, but costly.